# Spark/kryo/Joda time: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark, jodatime, kryo

I'm getting :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone.getInfo(CachedDateTimeZone.java:143)
    at org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone.getOffset(CachedDateTimeZone.java:103)
    at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.convertUTCToLocal(DateTimeZone.java:925)
    at org.joda.time.chrono.ZonedChronology$ZonedDateTimeField.get(ZonedChronology.java:432)
    at org.joda.time.base.AbstractDateTime.getMillisOfDay(AbstractDateTime.java:240)
```

I configured kryo as followed:

```
val sparkConfiguration = new SparkConf().setAppName("Session Logs to Parquet Job").set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
  sparkConfiguration.registerKryoClasses(Array(
      classOf[org.joda.time.DateTime],
      classOf[org.joda.time.Interval],
      classOf[org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder],
      classOf[org.joda.time.tz.FixedDateTimeZone],
      Class.forName("org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone$Info"),
      ClassTag(Class.forName("org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone$Info")).wrap.runtimeClass,
      classOf[org.joda.time.tz.CachedDateTimeZone]
    )
  )
```

I'm actually using : getHourOfDay(dt)
Where dt is a datetime. And the goal is to use kryo serializer in spark.
Joda 2.9.3.

What am I missing?
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It seems the deserialized CachedDateTimeZone instance is corrupted... Joda and Kryo are not good friends. It also seems AbstractDateTime is more internal API and should not be referenced directly by users as stated in http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html so you should avoid using it directly if it os the cade. Are you using joda 2.2? Could you add a piece of your code? Could you also tell what is your goal? This might help to get workarounds.